# Xcode 6.3 missing required architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, compiler-errors

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/user/Documents/project/IMDRequest_ARC_vHFZ.0/IMDRequest.sim,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (arm64):
>   /Users/user/Documents/project/IMDRequest_ARC_vHFZ.0/IMDRequest.simignoring
>   file /Users/user/Documents/project/IMDRequest_ARC_vHFZ.0/IMDRequest.a,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/user/Documents/project/IMDRequest_ARC_vHFZ.0/IMDRequest.a (2
>   slices)

I am getting this error when compile in 64 bit..

Its works find on 32bit.. But i can't find this file in 64bit architecture. So what should i do ?
I already read this question but my question is differ .. That path and architecture already set in my project.

Any one help me to convert .a file to arm64 .a file ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many questions like this on this site.  Why was the question upvoted?  It shows no effort on the part of the poster.  Suspicious...

Comment: Droppy my question is totally different you not understand probably.

Comment: No it's not different at all, and you are clearly the one who doesn't understand. The votes on your questions show your level of understanding and effort.

Comment: Ok fine so you answer a question only for your votes thats good

Comment: I'm talking about your questions.  You have consistently shown a lack of effort and understanding.

Comment: I am understand very well and also i worked 2 days on above query.

Comment: Yeah you clearly understand.  Explain how  "convert .a file to arm64 .a file" works then.  What is involved in that?

Comment: "You have consistently shown a lack of understanding."   I thought this comment was quite harsh, until I checked Malay's other questions, and found this one: "How [can I] install Xcode in windows 7?"    Ah, perhaps Droppy has a point...!!!